# How to update metadata in Azure.Storage.Blob

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I only find a code on adding metadata to a blob in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata?tabs=dotnet)

But there is not documentation of how to edit the blob's metadata

Is Azure.Storage.Blob dont have a way to modify the blob's metadata?

Comment: What about `SetMetadataAsync`?

Comment: @mtkachenko - you should put your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @mtkachenko - It somehow requires me to pass parameter in calling SetMetadataAsync..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SetMetadata and SetMetadataAsync will overwrite any existing value of a property that you have set in the past.

You can therefore either directly overwrite with a new value, or use GetMetadata(Async) first to retrieve the existing value, edit it, and then write it back using SetMetadata(Async).

You pass in an IDictionary to SetMetadata with the keys and values you want to set.

Any properties not set in your IDictionary will remain untouched on the blob.